# I distinctly remember 0 being the sign for on, or a closed circuit. Does anyone else recall learning it backwards?

Tags: binary

Is it just my false memory or does anyone else remember learning that.  The 1 if line represented open circuit for off.  I was floored to find out it’s the  opposite now.  So just like the bearstained Bears, fruit of the loom cornucopia and Shazam with Dunbar. Is this a mass false memory also?  Did anyone learn this 10 years or more ago and what do u remember?

Comment: what circuit are you talking about?

Comment: Impossible to say without more context. The mapping between a logical 1 (asserted) and a logical 0 depends on the circuit. Some opens indicate a 1 and some opens indicate a 0.

Comment: Some circuits are active low (for reasons related to historical limitations of fabrication and device physics). Others happen to use active-low, 0-is-closed signalling for practical purposes that are still fully applicable today. It depends on the circuit - the datasheets and circuit design themselves are what tell you how to interpret high/low vs open/closed vs 1/0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To aid in clarification, I believe the question is referencing these symbols: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_symbol

Comment: I think it's just you :-)

Comment: you may be remembering an on/off switch that was wired incorrectly

Comment: I'm Olde-ish. I've been looking at stuff like this for ~= 60 years. I don't recall seeing what you are describing in practice. (I'm in NZ).

Comment: I remember contextualizing it that way, with `0/O/circle` meaning "on" because it represented a continuous/closed circuit, and `1/l/line` meaning "off" because it represented an open/broken circuit.  But I'm pretty sure that was me learning it wrong, not the concept actually being taught backwards (specifically, the class was learning about "open" and "closed" circuits; don't think anything specific was said about switch markings, I just saw a switch with those markings around that time and assumed I should apply the concepts from the class towards them).

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking abut the markings on or near a power switch, then:

< circle > = off.  Completely off.  No little 1 W housekeeping supply running.  And, the actual symbol is a circle, not a zero or capital "O".

< vertical line > = on.  Full power is available to the device, lethal voltages might be present, etc.  The symbol is a vertical line, not a 1 or lower-case L.